# MySQL aggregate function to find closest value

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, is there any aggregate function (or any other method) to find closest value to specific value?

For example, I'm looking for addresses, where house number is 15. Or, when some streets doesn't have house no 15, closest house number (like 14 or 16) should be returned:

```
SELECT closest(house_no, 15), street_name
FROM addresses
GROUP BY street_name
```

Since there's need to aggregate, I can't see any help from `ORDER BY ABS(house_no - 15) LIMIT 1` which could be used to get single result.

Comment: no, there's no "nearest" function, so the `order by abs()` hack is all you can do. worst case, you can use a subquery to calculate the `house_no -15` stuff, then group/filter in the parent query.

Comment: Sorry, what's wrong with the ABS method? Why is there a need to aggregate?

Comment: @Strawberry I need to aggregate, since I need results for all streets. As alternative, I can do postprocessing in PHP (some other processing is involved in my workflow, anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(street VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,house_no INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(street,house_no)
);


INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('street_1',11),
('street_1',12),
('street_1',13),
('street_1',14),
('street_2',12),
('street_2',13),
('street_2',14),
('street_2',15),
('street_3',13),
('street_3',14),
('street_3',16),
('street_4',16),
('street_4',17),
('street_4',18),
('street_4',19);

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT street, MIN(ABS(house_no-15)) best_match FROM my_table GROUP BY street) y 
    ON y.street = x.street 
   AND y.best_match = ABS(x.house_no-15);
+----------+----------+
| street   | house_no |
+----------+----------+
| street_1 |       14 |
| street_2 |       15 |
| street_3 |       14 |
| street_3 |       16 |
| street_4 |       16 |
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Now that was neat! Thanks!